# MySQL 5.7 stuck forever "waiting for table level lock"

Tags: mysql

I have a webserver with a MySQL database. It holds several databases serving my various projects. Since Upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04 it has given me a lot of trouble in general. This question specifically is about a situation that a table is locked with a table level lock with no obvious reason why the lock is not removed quickly.

I have a lot of stuck queries like so:

```
581723  algebrainc_ro   localhost   algebrainc  Query   10309   Waiting for table level lock    SELECT\n  *\nFROM inventory\nWHERE inventory_id = '21601'
581724  algebrainc_ro   localhost   algebrainc  Query   10309   Waiting for table level lock    SELECT\n  *\nFROM inventory\nWHERE inventory_id = '21592'
581725  algebrainc_ro   localhost   algebrainc  Query   10309   Waiting for table level lock    SELECT\n  *\nFROM inventory\nWHERE inventory_id = '21602'
581726  algebrainc_ro   localhost   algebrainc  Query   10309   Waiting for table level lock    SELECT\n  *\nFROM inventory\nWHERE inventory_id = '21596'
581729  algebrainc_ro   localhost   algebrainc  Query   10306   Waiting for table level lock    SELECT inventory_id, ebay_title FROM inventory WHERE ebay_id = '32999992936'
581730  algebrainc  localhost   algebrainc  Query   10282   Waiting for table level lock    SELECT \n  complete_status status,\n  ebay_transactions.inventory_id,\n  ebay_transactions.ebay_id, \n  quantity, purchase_price, \n  ebay_title \nFROM ebay_transactions, inventory \nWHERE \n  ebay_transactions.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id \n  AND created_date > date_add( now(), interval -7 day )\nORDER BY \n  created_date
```

After a while of poking around and looking for nothing in `performance_schema` such as `table_handles` and `metadata_locks`, I did not find much.

After a while I realized that it happens because of `mysqldump` processes that I do periodically to dump one particular table. I had a dozen stuck `mysqldump` processes (called by cron) like these:

```
ichudov   1178  0.0  0.0  29004  3248 pts/46   Ss+  20:24   0:00 mysqldump -ualgebrainc -px xxxxxxxx algebrainc XXXXXXXX_posts
ichudov   1394  0.0  0.0  29004   900 pts/26   Ss+  Jun23   0:00 mysqldump -ualgebrainc -px xxxxxxxx algebrainc XXXXXXXX_posts
ichudov   2537  0.0  0.0  29004   920 pts/22   Ss+  Jun24   0:00 mysqldump -ualgebrainc -px xxxxxxxx algebrainc XXXXXXXX_posts
```

(table name masked for privacy)

After killing `mysqldump` processes, table locks were removed and everything went back to normal.

But why do `mysqldump` processes lock things up and do not work?

Comment: Is the inventory table InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Igor - how did u work this out?

Answer (score 3):

**Cause:**  table level lock during mysqldump which is the reason for slowness since the table  is using MyISAM engine

**Resolution:** Convert MyISAM to Innodb, for row level locking,

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Refer: [myisam lock during mysqldump](http://www.infradbas.com/2016/08/mysql-administration-mysqldump-table-lock.html)